# Hello! Can you please tell me what function the following verb occupies in the sentence?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

> Prascovie Fédorovna, une femme petite et grosse, qui, malgré tous ses efforts, allait en s’élargissant depuis les épaules jusqu’à sa base, toute vêtue de noir, la tête couverte d’une dentelle, les sourcils étrangement relevés, comme ceux de la dame qui se tenait debout en face du cercueil, sortit de ses appartements avec d’autres dames et, *les ayant accompagnées* dans la chambre mortuaire, elle dit : « L’office des morts va commencer ; entrez ».

**"Tolstoï la mort d'Ivan Ilitch"**

I don't understand if the verb *accompagner* it's in the gérondif passé mode or participate passé composé. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La formule signifie ici : "ayant accompagné les autres dames"

On aurait pu le formuler aussi comme ceci :

> - [...] avec d’autres dames et, **une fois qu'elle les eut** accompagnées dans la chambre mortuaire, elle dit :« L’office des morts va commencer ; entrez ».
> - [...] avec d’autres dames et, **après les avoir** accompagnées dans la chambre mortuaire, elle dit :« L’office des morts va commencer ; entrez ».
> - [...] avec d’autres dames et, **tandis qu'elle les avait** accompagnées dans la chambre mortuaire, elle dit :« L’office des morts va commencer ; entrez ».

Answer (score 1):

Le gérondif passé est une forme conjuguée indiquant une notion d'antériorité qui se forme avec le participe présent de l'auxiliaire être (étant) ou avoir (ayant) et on rajoute le participe passé du verbe à conjuguer qui s'accorde selon les règles d'accord du participe passé.

Donc c'est du gérondif passé.

Comment: Merci beaucoup !

Comment: je vous en prie, avec plaisir !